# How to get the access token in a controller of a protected resource

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

How do I get the access token as a string inside my controller of a protected resource?  I want to call `ConsumerTokenServices.revokeToken(String tokenValue)` from this controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `AuthenticationDetails` in the authenticated principal. By default it will contain the access token value, along with IP and path information.